# How can I change the default blue color of a selected item in Navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I tried to use android:listSelector, but it works only when I click on the listview cell, how can I change the highlight color of a selected cell, so that the cell will be stay highlighted with that color? 
Many thanks.

[highlight in blue](http://www.qingqingplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/device-2013-11-28-180314-576x1024.png)

[highlight in orange](http://img.blog.csdn.net/20130602221828578)

Answer (score 16):

add this to your layout you use to show the elements of the listview

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

Create a file res/drawable/my_background.xml with the following content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/blue" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Replace the @color/blue with the color of your choice.
Then, in your theme, add the following line :

```
<item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/my_background</item>
```

Comment: i don't know why but this isn't working for me.. I think that it should

Comment: how about change the text color of navigation drawer when selected?

Comment: add this to the selector  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/YourColor" /> <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/YourColor" />

Answer (score 0):

you may need to implement your own adapter in this case, and return your custom layout which background color is set to "highlight in orange". Something like this:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View your_custom_view = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            your_custom_view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_custom_view_layout, null);
        } else {
            your_custom_view = convertView;
        }

        return your_custom_view;
    }
```